# boost-build / bjam: execute a script post install (make 'install' a dependency of executing a script)

Tags: boost, boost-build, bjam, b2

Using `boost-build` / `bjam`, is it possible to execute a script after an `install` rule has completed?

I have a `Jamfile` which defined an executable (`exe`), and then installs it (`install`). I want to execute a script after the `install` step.

**Jamfile:**

```
exe my_app
  : [ glob *.cc ]
  : <link>static
  ;

install .
  : my_app 
  ;

{ execute script after install here }
```

I am aware that I can execute a script

```
[ SHELL "path/to/script.sh" ] ;
```

But I don't know how to have `install` be a dependency of the execution of that script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use `notfile` target as described [here](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/builtins/raw.html). Although it is not explicitly stated there, `notfile` target also accepts a list of dependencies, so you can pass the install target as a source for `notfile`.

```
import notfile ;

install install-app : my_app : <location>. ;
notfile . : @post-install : install-app ;
actions post-install
{
    echo Install is now done.
}
```

Comment: @mordeen try [here](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.builtins.raw).