# bjam fails the notfile example from the documentation?

Tags: bjam

I have seen [boost-build / bjam: execute a script post install (make 'install' a dependency of executing a script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496622/boost-build-bjam-execute-a-script-post-install-make-install-a-dependency-o) where there is a recommendation for using `notfile`. Then I found the https://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/builtins/raw.html page with a basic example, where I've added the `import notfile`:

```
import notfile;
notfile echo_something : @echo ;
actions echo
{
    echo "something"
}
```

And I've tried this snippet in a Jamroot file of a project. If I do not have the `import notfile`, then it fails with:

```
...
Jamroot:57: in modules.load
ERROR: rule "notfile" unknown in module "Jamfile</home/USER/src/myproject>".
/usr/share/boost-build/src/build/project.jam:372: in load-jamfile
/usr/share/boost-build/src/build/project.jam:64: in load
/usr/share/boost-build/src/build/project.jam:142: in project.find
/usr/share/boost-build/src/build-system.jam:618: in load
/usr/share/boost-build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import
/usr/share/boost-build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
/usr/share/boost-build/boost-build.jam:8: in module scope
```

If I have the `import notfile;` then it fails with:

```
Jamroot:56: Unescaped special character in argument notfile;
/usr/share/boost-build/src/kernel/modules.jam:258: in modules.import from module modules
error: When loading multiple modules, no specific rules or renaming is allowed
/usr/share/boost-build/src/build/project.jam:1121: in import from module Jamfile</home/USER/src/myproject>
Jamroot:62: in modules.load from module Jamfile</home/USER/src/myproject>
/usr/share/boost-build/src/build/project.jam:372: in load-jamfile from module project
/usr/share/boost-build/src/build/project.jam:64: in load from module project
/usr/share/boost-build/src/build/project.jam:142: in project.find from module project
/usr/share/boost-build/src/build-system.jam:618: in load from module build-system
/usr/share/boost-build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import from module modules
/usr/share/boost-build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build from module
/usr/share/boost-build/boost-build.jam:8: in module scope from module
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed the "Jamroot:56: Unescaped special character in argument notfile" while writing the question which finally made sense (errors like "error: When loading multiple modules, no specific rules or renaming is allowed" are completely misleading and useless) - and I realized, I had written:

```
 import notfile;
```

... that is, with semicolon directly after the word - it seems, here space is required; so with this change:

```
 import notfile ;
```

... things start working again.